# align list items of listview in 4 columns

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

i have this xml i haded for each column i want  a table layout and a table row, but i cant align the columns i tried put android:layout_weight but id doesn alin the right way can anyone help me.

output for example:

xxxxxx     11111     11111      11111

xml ;

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
 >


 <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"          
 >




    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

    >

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id_instit"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/descricao"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="6dip"
                android:paddingTop="6dip"
                android:textSize="17dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" 

                />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>





    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

     >

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/data"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="6dip"
                android:paddingTop="6dip"
                android:textSize="17dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>




    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/data2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="6dip"
                android:paddingTop="6dip"
                android:textSize="17dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>




    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >


        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/qtd"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="6dip"
                android:paddingTop="6dip"
                android:textSize="17dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>




    </TableRow>


 </TableLayout>
```

Comment: `align list items of listview` - and where is the ListView?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >
    <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="My Report view"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>
    <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView2"
                android:text="" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="M"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="T"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="W"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="T"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="F"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:text="Day High"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="xxxxx" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="11111" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="34°C" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="11111" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="11111" >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: no because if the text is long the others textviews get afected

Answer (score 0):

for the previous answer if this is your problem use android:strechColumns="index_of_your_column" to solve it.

Comment: my is that i have for example "viana do castelo"   "12" and then in another line "castelo"  "11" and i cant align the 2 colum because the 1 string is smaller

Answer (score 0):

when you use TableLayout the width of a column is the width of largest element among all the rows of the table.

here is the example of code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text1"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text2"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text3"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text4"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

notice that the remaining unused width is distributed on the last column. if you want to distribute remaining unused space equally among all columns use **android:strechColumns="*"** inside TableLayout declaration